# Heated bar with one fixed end kept at a fixed temperature and one end kept insulated?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm struggling to understand heat conduction. If we have a finite heated rod where the temperature of one end is kept at a constant temperature, but the other end is perfectly insulated, what will the temperature distribution across the rod look like at a specific time? Will it decrease as you get to the insulated end or will the heat build up across the rod?

Comment: Is the temporarily changing with time or is the rod at a steady state?

Comment: The rod is changing with time,

Comment: Are the sides of the rod insulated? If not, at what temperature are they kept?

Comment: After a long time, the temperature throughout the bar will be the same as that of the constant temperature end.

Comment: Such a problem can be solved via the methods of partial differential equations I'm going to assume that wasn't exactly the intent here but one of asking qualitatively vs quantitatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk a little about a couple widely used boundary conditions and how certain configurations can lead to certain expected behavior and then to quantitative equations.

Let's keep three parameters in mind: (1) the temperature at a certain point (say, an end, or somewhere in the middle, (2) the temperature *slope* at and around the point, and (3) the temperature *curvature* (very informally, a smile or a frown) at and around the point.

(Math: These are $T(x_0)$, $\frac{\partial T(x_0)}{\partial x}$, and $\frac{\partial^2T(x_0)}{\partial x^2}$ at point $x_0$.)

First, a comment on curvature: For conductive heat transfer, curvature in the temperature profile indicates that the profile is still changing or that heat is being generated within the system. In the absence of heat generation, if steady state is reached after a long time at constant boundary conditions, the temperature profile is a straight line between the end temperatures (whatever they end up being, if they're not held constant). Put another way, conduction acts to smooth out temperature distribution hills and valleys.

(Math: The solution to the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}\sim\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}$ when transients have died down ($\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}\to 0$) is $T(x)=C_1 x+C_2$, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants from integrating $\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}=0$. This is a straight line.)

A **constant-temperature** boundary condition may be the easiest to understand. The system touches a large, well-conducting reservoir at a certain temperature, causing that end to be essentially "clamped" to that temperature. (Math: $T(0)$ is a constant, where we take $x=0$ as the end in question.) Note that this says nothing about the $slope$ or $curvature$ of the temperature profile at that end of the system. However, we can always say, based on [Fourier's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier%27s_law), that the flux or heat flow per unit area $q$ (in watts per square meter, for example) points opposite to the temperature gradient and is mediated by that gradient and the system thermal conductivity $k$. (Math: $q(x_0,t)=-k\frac{\partial T(x_0)}{\partial x}$.) This is useful information, as you might know the flux or be able to calculate it based on what you know about the system.

An **insulated** boundary condition is the focus of the original question. This condition is easy to visualize but perhaps harder to interpret. Physically, the system is adjacent to a material of very low thermal conductivity (that also blocks convection and radiation, for completeness). The temperature is not fixed and indeed is free to wander. However, since the heat flux is essentially zero through the insulator, the temperature *slope* at the end is now fixed through Fourier's law, as discussed above. (Math: $-k\frac{\partial T(0)}{\partial x}=0$.) Now we can answer one of the questions: *what will the temperature distribution across the rod look like at a specific time? Will it decrease as you get to the insulated end...* No; the temperature distribution next to an insulated area is always flat. Now, it may initially exhibit or acquire curvature near this area as heat conduction acts transiently within the rod, but since all curvature must vanish over time, the steady state, if it exists, requires a constant slope, and therefore a zero slope when insulation exists.

From this, we can broadly address the question:

For a system with a constant temperature applied in some areas and other areas insulated, a steady state is ultimately reached where the entire system lies at that applied temperature.

For a system with a constant heat flux applied in some areas and other areas insulated, there is no steady state; the temperature continues to change because of the lack of energy balance.

For a system with a constant heat flux applied in some areas and other areas held at a constant temperature, the steady state involves constant output heat flux through the areas being held at constant temperature; this output flux equals the total input flux. A nonconstant temperature profile arises in response to this flux, in accordance with Fourier's law.

Does this clarify the points you were wondering about?

Answer (score 0):

First, the setup isn't stated as clearly as it could be. In a problem like this, I would expect that the rod is in contact with a heat reservoir. Heat can flow in our out across this boundary. I would expect that the rest of the rod is insulated so that heat cannot flow into or out of the rod elsewhere.

So you have a rod where one end is hotter than the other. Heat can diffuse along the rod. I would expect the temperature to change for a while until it reaches a state where heat diffuses into a point as fast as it diffuses out. You should think about that. What do you expect the final state to be? Where does heat come from? Where does it go? What do you expect will happen if more heat flows in than out?

Typically you would want to know the initial condition. For this problem, the temperature of the bar is often uniform everywhere in the bar. Then the bar is brought into contact with the reservoir. Is that the case with this problem?

You might also want to figure out the boundary conditions. You have enough information.

Once you have a clearer picture, you might be able to set up the diffusion equation and solve it.